# Spring boot returning error 404 html page not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications, controller

I'm trying to return index.html which is placed under src/main/resources/templates but it seems that it is not loading.

StackTrace

```
2020-07-24 00:09:11.881 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2020-07-24 00:09:11.884 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.Alex.Flights.FlightsController#getIndexForm(ModelMap)
2020-07-24 00:09:11.885 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2020-07-24 00:09:11.902 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2020-07-24 00:09:11.902 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'index', model {userForm=Flights [flightNumber=dummy, origin=dummy, destination=dummy, takeOffTime=dummy, landingTime=dummy, flightDuration=dummy, takeOffDate=Fri Jul 24 00:09:11 SGT 2020, landingDate=Fri Jul 24 00:09:11 SGT 2020, flightReturn=false], org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.userForm=org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors}
2020-07-24 00:09:11.903 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [index]
2020-07-24 00:09:11.905 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/index", parameters={}
2020-07-24 00:09:11.907 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-07-24 00:09:11.908 DEBUG 17204 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
```

Method in controller

```
 package com.Alex.Flights;
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getIndexForm(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new Flights("dummy", "dummy", "dummy", "dummy", "dummy","dummy", new Date(), new Date(), false));
    return "index";
}
```

Main

```
package com.Alex.Mains;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.Alex.JPA", "com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"
})
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.Alex.UserPackage", "com.Alex.Flights"})
public class JpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpaApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image: Project structure]

Answer (score 0):

it seems like it is only looking in folders like /resources but doesn't go to look in /templates.

Solution is to define you own ViewResolver bean and set it up
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-view-resolver-tutorial

Comment: I've tried putting the .html in resources but it didn't work. I don't think it's a problem with the placement and my other projects worked with it in templates, also without a custom viewresolver

Comment: if you add thymeleaf in springboot it produces it's own viewresolver and adds .html at the end. Without thymeleaf or other view resolver it won't know where to look or to add .html